# How to get API key of user's YouTube Data API after Google firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, youtube, firebase-authentication, youtube-data-api

I'am making a **firebase** PWA that shows a custom YouTube home. So, I want to list the videos of a user's YouTube home.

For that I'am using the Youtube Data API v3 and **want to use the user's API key** (coz if i use my API key, they will get my recommendations, right?).

The user will be logged into the site **using Google Auth**.
So, how can I use that information and

- access their Google API console
- get their API key
- enable their Youtube data API
- get their recommended results

(I can accept any wild method)

Comment: did you get any way of doing this? I'm also looking for this one.

Comment: @TheLazyProgrammer Nop. Nothing. Shattered my ambitious project of making a cool looking youtube.

Comment: oh, do you know any npm library that simplifies the youtube data API?

Comment: No, I'm still learning and don't know anything. Sorry. I did search a lot for doing this, but never found a solution. (Think there's python libraries in github that does the same with oAuth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is officially impossible. Hacks might exist, but not dependable. Sorry.